# For Loop Scoping with 2D Array

Tags: javascript, scope, big-o

I am working on an Advent Code Challenge and have run into a hall.  I solved this error before, but in this instance, I am stuck.  The following code is giving me a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined.` in relation to `switch (diagArray[i][j])`.

My thought is that `diagArray` is out of scope.  Is that true?

Please, any help is great!

```js
const diagArray = [
  [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1],
  [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1]
 ]; // example data
  
  for(let i = 0; i < diagArray.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < diagArray.length; i++) {
    let gammaRate = ''
    let epsilonRate = ''
    let ones = 0
    let zeros = 0
    let rates = []

    switch (diagArray[i][j]) {
      case 1:
        ones++
        break
      case 0:
        zeros++
        break
      default:
        break
    }

    if (ones > zeros) {
      gammaRate+=1
      epsilonRate+=0
    } else {
      gammaRate+=0
      epsilonRate+=1
    }

    rates.push([gammaRate, epsilonRate])
    // console.log(rates)
  }
}
```

Comment: the upper limit in your inner `for` loop should be `diagArray[i].length`, not `diagArray.length`

Comment: it's definitely not out of scope - you get a ReferenceError for using an undeclared or out of scope variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second iteration was increasing the `i` variable instead of `j` while iterating to the length of `diagArray` instead of `diagArray[i]`.

You can use the Console API to debug your values to find out where the issue originates from without having to guess.

```js
const diagArray = [
  [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1],
  [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1]
 ]; // example data
  
  for(let i = 0; i < diagArray.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < diagArray[i].length; j++) {
    let gammaRate = ''
    let epsilonRate = ''
    let ones = 0
    let zeros = 0
    let rates = []
    
    console.log(`${i}:${j} = ${diagArray[i][j]}`)

    switch (diagArray[i][j]) {
      case 1:
        ones++
        break
      case 0:
        zeros++
        break
      default:
        break
    }

    if (ones > zeros) {
      gammaRate+=1
      epsilonRate+=0
    } else {
      gammaRate+=0
      epsilonRate+=1
    }

    rates.push([gammaRate, epsilonRate])
    // console.log(rates)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(let i = 0; i < diagArray.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < diagArray.length; i++) {
```

This here has multiple problems.

The first for loop is fine, but the second one needs be bounded by the length of the inner array:

```
diagArray[i].length
```

And it's also currently incrementing the first loops counts with `i++`. That needs to be `j++`

---

Working example:

```js
const diagArray = [
  [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1],
  [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1]
 ]; // example data
  
for (let i = 0; i < diagArray.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < diagArray[i].length; j++) {
    let gammaRate = ''
    let epsilonRate = ''
    let ones = 0
    let zeros = 0
    let rates = []

    switch (diagArray[i][j]) {
      case 1:
        ones++
        break
      case 0:
        zeros++
        break
      default:
        break
    }

    if (ones > zeros) {
      gammaRate+=1
      epsilonRate+=0
    } else {
      gammaRate+=0
      epsilonRate+=1
    }

    rates.push([gammaRate, epsilonRate])
    console.log(rates)
  }
}
```

---

Also it's usually not advisable to have loops like this for iterating arrays, since, as you've discovered, it's very easy to screw up the indices.

I recommend interating over the values of the arrays instead:

```
for (const row of diagArray) {
  for (const value of row) {
```

```js
const diagArray = [
  [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1],
  [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1]
 ]; // example data
  
for (const row of diagArray) {
  for (const value of row) {
    let gammaRate = ''
    let epsilonRate = ''
    let ones = 0
    let zeros = 0
    let rates = []

    switch (value) {
      case 1:
        ones++
        break
      case 0:
        zeros++
        break
      default:
        break
    }

    if (ones > zeros) {
      gammaRate+=1
      epsilonRate+=0
    } else {
      gammaRate+=0
      epsilonRate+=1
    }

    rates.push([gammaRate, epsilonRate])
    console.log(rates)
  }
}
```

Comment: Great question!!! Thanks 

Comment: Awesome thanks Alex

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the second for loop it says `diagArray.length`, and it should be `diagArray[i].length` so that you are getting the length of the second array.

Comment: This won't fix the error since the outer arrays length is only 3, which is smaller than the length of the inner arrays. I'm sure sure it's a bug, but it wont fix this alone.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the second for loop expression like this.

```
for (let j = 0; j < diagArray[i].length; j++) {
```